# Displaying values in checkbox from database

Tags: php

I tried doing writing this code, however the values don't show

```
<?php
$queryc = "select day from day";
$resultc = mysqli_query($link,$queryc) or die(mysqli_error($link));
while($rowc=  mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultc)){
    echo $rowc['day'];
    echo'<br><input type=checkbox name=day[] value='.$rowc['day'].'><br>';
}
?>
```

The problem is in $rowc['day'] when I put it as value but when I try to echo it separately the day shows up
so what might be the problem?

Comment: View your HTML source and var_dump.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Input checkbox doesn't display its value. You have to put it out of the tag aswell.

```
<?php
$queryc = "select day from day";
$resultc = mysqli_query($link,$queryc) or die(mysqli_error($link));
while($rowc=  mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultc)){
    echo $rowc['day'];
    echo '<br><input type="checkbox" name=day[] value="'.$rowc['day'].'">'.$rowc['day'].'<br>';
}
?>
```

Comment: It's so simple but I was missing it. I was echoing the sentence alone and not knowing why!!Thanks u saved my day

Answer (score 0):

`<input type="checkbox" />` do have a `checked` attribute. If you want to set checkbox checked if `$rowc['day']` do have value and not checked otherwise you can use following code for that

```
while($rowc=  mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultc)){
    echo $rowc['day'];
    if(isset($rowc['day']) && !empty($rowc['day'])){
        echo'<br><input type=checkbox name=day[] value="'.$rowc['day'].'" checked="checked"><br>';
    }else{
        echo'<br><input type=checkbox name=day[] value='.$rowc['day'].'><br>';
    }
}
```

secondly you missed double quotes around the value inside input tag.

Comment: OP (zozi) says: *"however the values don't show"* so I doubt that your adding `checked="checked"` has any bearing on the question.